# Should I always use redux-saga `call` effect for functions that return promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux-saga

Assuming I have a function

```
function* request(url) {
   return global.fetch(url).then(response =>
     _.result(response, 'json'))
}
```

Both code examples work fine to me

```
const {data} = yield call(request, 'http://example.com/api');
yield put(actionSuccess(data));
```

and

```
const {data} = yield request('http://example.com/api');
yield put(actionSuccess(data));
```

Therefore the question. What is an advantage of using the `call` effect for functions that return promises?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some benefits of using `call()`:

1. [Testability](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html), the only benefit the docs seem to mention (lower half of the page). I recommend [redux-saga-test-plan](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan), it allows to mock `call()` and other effects by directly supplying the return value.
2. More fine-grained [task cancellation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html). Sagas are ES6 generators, which only yield control (back to redux-saga middleware) when you use the `yield` statement. These are the only points where cancellation can happen. A `yield call()` gives redux-saga an opportunity to cancel the task right before it's about to make that no longer needed call. Task cancellation is performed using `gen.return()` generator method. <sup>[[1]](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#canceltask) [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return)</sup>
3. More fine-grained task scheduling in general. Redux-saga's concurrency model is basically cooperative multitasking. And JavaScript is single-threaded. A So when you `yield`, it's the only opportunity for redux-saga middleware to do any kind of scheduling other tasks. (I'm not sure how good redux-saga is at this, though.)

For more information, I think it's best to open an issue on redux-saga's Github to ask the maintainer directly.

**UPD:** As this answer is getting attention: *think twice before using redux-saga.* It provides:

- A now obsolete generator-based version of `async/await` available since ES7
- [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) (channels) Golang users should be familiar with
- Task cancellation (but you cannot wait for your "cleanup" block to terminate!)

If you want to use Redux, I recommend opting for something simpler, like async thunks. You can have channels with [`async-csp`](https://github.com/dvlsg/async-csp) and proper cancellation with [`cancellationtoken`](https://github.com/conradreuter/cancellationtoken).

Comment: Yeah, makes sense only if unit tests runner walks through saga generator step by step. Although if [`SagaTester`](https://github.com/wix/redux-saga-tester) approach is used, when a saga is executed natively during unit test, having `call` doesn't bring any value.

Comment: Although for task cancellation and cleanup I assumed they needed the power of generators to allow the middleware to orchestrate? The redux-saga site claims: "(kind of like async/await, but generators have a few more awesome features we need)".

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is visibility into what is going on in the app.

You want to know **when, why and how** the state is updated <sup>[[1]](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation)</sup>.

`call` <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/v0.16.2/src/internal/io.js#L100)</sup> triggers an effect when a saga monitor is configured on the saga middleware [before running the effect](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/v0.16.2/src/internal/proc.js#L352) and [after the effect is resolved](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/v0.16.2/src/internal/proc.js#L370).

With a saga monitor configured and without using `call` effect, I see this in the monitor logs.

[image: Without call]

However with `call` effect,

[image: With call]

Comment: Using `yield request` will make sure that the promise is canceled if the parent saga is canceled. I went through debugging and got my breakpoint stoped in `resolvePromise` [of redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/resolvePromise.js).

Comment: I used "saga-monitor" to see if there is any difference in the debug trace information we get from using or not using `call`. In fact, there is almost no difference.

This is the trace line with using `call`:
`effectTriggered    {effectId: 11, parentEffectId: 10, label: "", effect: request}`

and this is without

`effectTriggered    {effectId: 11, parentEffectId: 10, label: "", effect: {...}}`

Basically, I am losing the `request` function name in logs, but it could be sacrificed due to increased code readability.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You're correct that the `put` is used for dispatch actions to store. Other effects are sent to the saga middleware. I took a look using the saga-monitor-example and yes, the function name is unknown in the log. I'll update my answer to reflect my current findings about this matter.